Nash blowup and resolution of singularities
We work over the field of complex numbers. We recall the definition of the Nash blowup (sometimes called as canonical blowup?) from the preprint https://arxiv.org/abs/2409.19767 : Let $X \subset \mathbb{A}^n$ be an irreducible normal variety and let $\mathrm{Sing}(X) \subset X$ denotes the singular locus of the variety. Consider the map
$$
\Phi : X \setminus Sing(X) \rightarrow Grass(d, n)
$$
defined by sending a smooth point $x$ to its tangent space $T_xX$. Let $X^*$ be the Zariski closure of the graph of $\Phi$. Then there is a natural map $\nu : X^* \rightarrow X$. The map $\nu$ is biratinal by construction and is called as the Nash blowup.
The authors of loc. cit. show that there exists varieties in any dimension $\geq 4$ such that after any number of iterates of Nash blowups, the resulting variety is not smooth. The examples given are simplicial toric varieties which are known to be rational homology  manifolds. Since I am only concerned with cohomological aspect of resolution of singularities, let me ask the following question
Qestion : Does every variety become a rational homology manifold after a sequence of Nash blowups?
Are there examples where the above question has a negative answer? Any comments or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.
